# Monkey Runner - Using it in a Java class to send commands to emulator

Tags: java, android, monkeyrunner

I am trying to make use of this monkey runner Java class [**here**](http://pastebin.com/iNELvh3r) which was obtained from [here](http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/2.0/development/tools/monkeyrunner/src/com/android/monkeyrunner/). It looks really good, however, every time I run it I get this error:

> 02:01:38 E/adb: Failed to get the adb version: Cannot run program
>   "adb": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file
>   specified

I make sure to forward and start the monkey server like so:

> adb forward tcp:1080 tcp:1080
>
> adb shell monkey --port 1080

I am running this class within eclipse. What am I doing wrong?

I would also appreciate links to examples of using the monkey runner in a Java class to send commands to an emulator. I don't want to use Python/Jython script I want to do it within a Java class.

Comment: If you'r using windows maybe the adb is not on the system path but on the user path. And eclipse is running it as another user and therefore can't find the adb.exe.

Comment: @Mannaz - I think you are right! I just added the full path instead of adb and it doesn't give me that error anymore. However, it does lead to a null pointer exception which I can work out. Do you mind adding the above as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'r using windows maybe the adb is not on the system path but on the user path. And eclipse is running it as another user and therefore can't find the adb.exe.